# LDAP - List groups

Tags: php, ldap

I need to list all groups within a certain group using PHP.  This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$ldap_dn = "ou=People,dc=something,dc=something,dc=something,dc=au";
$ldap_svr = "ldap.server.somewhere";
$ldap_domain = "domain.somewhere";
$conn=ldap_connect($ldap_svr) or die("Cannot connect to LDAP server!");

ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

ldap_bind($conn,"user@domain.somewhere","password");


$filter ="(ou=*)";
$justthese = array("ou");

$result=ldap_list($conn, $ldap_dn, $filter, $justthese) or die("No search data found."); 

$info = ldap_get_entries($conn, $result);

for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
    echo $info[$i]["ou"][0] . '<br />';
}
?>
```

This returns a list of groups, one of whch is 'Students', but I want to list all groups within 'Students'.  How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Fluffeh the Microsoft LDAP plugin allows me to search active directorys so I can tailor my PHP script accordingly, `e.g. $ldap_dn = "ou=Units,ou=Groups,dc=somewhere,dc=somewher,dc=somewhere,dc=au";`

So my mostly working code is:

```
<?php
$ldap_dn = "ou=Units,ou=Groups,dc=somewhere,dc=somewher,dc=somewhere,dc=au";
$ldap_svr = "ldap.server.somewhere";
$ldap_domain = "domain.somewhere";
$conn=ldap_connect($ldap_svr) or die("Cannot connect to LDAP server!");

ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

ldap_bind($conn,"user@domain.somewhere","password");


$filter ="(cn=*)";
$justthese = array('cn');

$result=ldap_list($conn, $ldap_dn, $filter, $justthese) or die("No search data found."); 

$info = ldap_get_entries($conn, $result);

for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
    echo $info[$i]["cn"][0] . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'all groups with the group Students'? Can you give us the DNs of one or two groups 'inside' the group Students?

Comment: FYI I'm listing groups by: `ldapsearch -x -LLL '(|(objectclass=posixgroup)(objectclass=groupofnames))' cn | grep ^cn` if that can help anybody..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually pass the search to it. Currently you are using:

```
$filter ="(ou=*)";
```

This will need to change to contain 'Students'. While I am no LDAP expert, I would guess at the following:

```
$filter ="(cn=Students)";
```

Most of the LDAP stuff I have done has been sheer trial and error rather than knowing what I am doing, but this might put you on the right path.

There is also a [Microsoft plugin - Active Directory Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) you can use to at least browse the LDAP so that you know what to search for and under what branch.

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh, changing the filter didn't do much, but I like your suggestion of the plugin.  That's very helpful!

Comment: @PeterBrowne Using that plugin and sheer trial and error was the only way I got my (simple) script up and running. It worked out, but I wouldn't say I totally understand every bit of the code and how it works :)